# Using ECDH when VPN keys are pre-shared

Tags: encryption

Do you need to implement ECDH (Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman) if the keys are pre-shared?

Comment: If you can establish a symmetric key out of band you can probably skip key exchange including ECDH

Comment: Are you talking about the VPN Pre-Shared-Key? PSK is commonly used in VPNs for authentication while (EC)DHE is used for encryption.

Comment: ECDH provides perfect forward secrecy which preshared keys don't.